# How to scp/tar files that are in between specific days?

Tags: files, tar, date, scp

I need to copy db log files between two suse servers where I am interested in files ONLY in between 10.3.2013 - 13.3.2013

It is desired to compress the files before copying so I tar them and scp. Currently I am using `tar -cvzf /tmp/saas_archive_logs.tar.gz /var/lib/edumate/backup/archive_logs/db2inst1/SAAS --newer-mtime=2013-03-10` that gives me all files from 10.3.2013 till now. But I don't need all of them. And I didn't find any tar switch.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As Bichoy indicated you can use the `find` command to find files with a specific access, create and modification time. However -mtime takes an offset in 24 hour increments and is not always convenient to calculate unless you want something from a specific amount of numbers of 'days' ago. You will need to combine that with `-daystart` to 'round' that to the beginning of the day.

I think more convenient in your case, is the -newermt option which takes a datestring (and not the name of a reference file like most -newerXY versions)

Combine that with `find`'s `-print0` option to handle files with spaces in the name and optionally `-type f` not to get any directories in the period you are interested in:

```
find /var/lib/edumate/backup/archive_logs/db2inst1/SAAS \
   -newermt 20130310 -not -newermt 20130314 -type f -print0 \
   | xargs -0 tar -cvzf /tmp/saas_archive_logs.tar.gz
```

There is one big problem with that: in case the number of files found becomes to long, `xargs` will invoke its command (in this case `tar`) multiple times as `xargs` needs to fit the arguments on the commandline which is not infinite.
To circumvent that I always use `cpio`, which reads filenames from stdin. With the `--format=ustar` parameter to get a POSIX tar file, and in your case you would need to pipe the output through `gzip` to get the desired result:

```
find /var/lib/edumate/backup/archive_logs/db2inst1/SAAS \
   -newermt 20130310 -not -newermt 20130314 -type f -print0 \
   | cpio --create --null  --format=ustar \
   | gzip > /tmp/saas_archive_logs.tar.gz
```

Comment: Can I specify hours and minutes when using your code?

Comment: I tried before posting my comment but ... "find: I cannot figure out how to interpret `201302050000' as a date or time"

Comment: @Radek The short answer is Yes. I would use YYYYMMDDThhmm in order not have to deal with spaces. The long answer: man find will tell you: Time specifications are interpreted as for the argument to the -d option of GNU date and with man date you will find `... a mostly free format human readable date string ..... A date string may contain items indicating calendar date, time of day, time zone, day of week, relative time, relative date, and numbers`

Comment: @Radek thanks for pointing the error out, since I could not edit my comment, I reinserted a new one with a `T` inserted between the Days and Hours. That I tested and works. Somehow `find` does not know how to split the string otherwise (probably because it could be YYMMDDhhmmss instead of YYYYMMDDhhmm. I thought that date would need a dot for the seconds (`.ss`) but that is probably only for setting the date.

Answer (score 6):

You can check the `find` command to get a list of the files that needs to be tared.
You can specify a start and end date (up to seconds precision) using the normal `-atime` , `-btime` , `-mtime` ... arguments in combination with the `-not` argument.
You can then pipe the output to `xargs` and then to `tar`. Check the man page of `find` for details about time arguments.

*Update:*
As Anthon suggested, you may use the +/- modifiers with `-mtime` to specify the period without using `-not`. Here is an example:

```
find . -mtime -5d2h3m10s -mtime +4d0h15m20s -print0 | xargs -0 tar cjvf mytar.tar.bz2
```

Where `d, h, m, s` corresponds to *days, hours, minutes* and *seconds* respectively. This will give files modified newer than `5d2h3m10s` and older than `4d0h15m20s`

Comment: the argument to `-mtime` has to be a offset in days that is not always unless you that offset is fixed between running times. You can also use `-mtime +X` and `-mtime -X` to specify before and after X days ago instead of using -not.

Comment: What would be the syntax to specify absolute date & time?